# Pesquisa comparando id de duas collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Preciso carregar os dados unindo dois id

Em um formulário preencho meu cliente com um ID.
Em outro formulário preencho outras informações e carrego  o ID do cliente.
Ou seja, ambos os formulários, enviam o mesmo ID para o banco.

Preciso gerar um *json* que tem as informações destes dois formulários.

Quando faço:

```
Contact.findOne({$and: [{_id: contact.Client.id}, {_id: client.id}]},function(err, contacts) {
```

nao funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez não entenda o que você queira, mas se `contact.Client.id` e `client.id` forem iguais, a query que você quer é:

```
Contact.findOne({ _id: contact.Client.id }, /*...*/)
```

Se eles forem diferentes e você quiser ambos os documentos referenciados:

```
Contact.find({ $or: [ { _id: contact.Client.id }, { _id: client.id } ] }, /*...*/)
```